# Why is a special cookie-banner not displayed in the Selenium-chromedriver test software?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, web-testing

For a web-test i call an online-shop which uses a special GDPR-cookie-banner. When I call this online store in a normal chrome browser, it is loaded and displayed.

However, when I call this online store with the test software (chromedriver, Selenium, Python), it is loaded but not displayed.

What is the reason and what can I do to display this banner?

Online-shop: https://www.uwaldu.de/

Browser snapshot with normal chrome browser:

[image]

Browser snapshot with webdriver:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you won't see the *special GDPR-cookie-banner*. But when I access the [website](https://uwaldu.de/) using a [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) initiated [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) *Browsing Context* the *GDPR-cookie-banner* is displayed perfectly everytime.

Code Block:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
driver.get("https://uwaldu.de/")
```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: GDPR]

Comment: Thank you very much. After I added "--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled" to my driver, I was able to see the banner. Without this argument, the banner stays away. Thank you very much for this hint.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you use chrome's "user agent" as some websites would load the banner only based on the browser and its properties.

EX: options.add_argument("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36")