# Detected on Headless Chrome Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless, rate-limiting

Im trying to scrape Amazon when running headless with a up to date UserAgent I am getting rate limited. When I # out the headless line I don't get detected or rate limited. Below is my code!

```
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
#options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36")
service = ChromeService(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
browser.get("https://www.amazon.com.au/Oculus-Quest-2-Virtual-Reality-Headset/dp/B08FSZ8QWH")
print(browser.page_source)
```

When I remove the # at options.add_argument("--headless") and I run the code I get a server busy line. Does anyone know of a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [avoid detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70508719/why-is-a-special-cookie-banner-not-displayed-in-the-selenium-chromedriver-test-s/70509053#70509053) using [google-chrome-headless](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-headless) add the following argument through *`add_argument()`* as follows:

> [`--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65994908/selenium-cant-open-a-second-page/65998533#65998533)

Sample Code:

```
options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com.au/Oculus-Quest-2-Virtual-Reality-Headset/dp/B08FSZ8QWH")
```

Comment: If I put it in options.add_experimental_option() I get an error `TypeError: ChromiumOptions.add_experimental_option() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'`

Do I just need to keep it in `options.add_argument`?

Comment: @HKGaming My bad, typo in the verbatim. Updated it, should have been `add_argument()`

Comment: Perfect seems to be working at the moment, thank you very much!