# Selenium user agent doesn't work on heroku

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, heroku, user-agent

I'm trying to get access to web site, but in headless mode I get this:

```
<html><head>
<title>Access Denied</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Access Denied</h1>
 
You don't have permission to access "http://www.bybit.com/fiat/trade/otc/?" on this server.<p>
Reference #18.3f62645f.1657282455.2f87631


</p></body></html>
```

So I us user agent by adding this:

```
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.50 Safari/537.36'
chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
```

It works well on my local machine, but when I deployed it on Heroku server, I'v got the same issue.

Main part of the code:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-features=NetworkService")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])


chrome_options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=800,600")
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.50 Safari/537.36'
chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')

bybit_url = 'https://www.bybit.com/fiat/trade/otc/?actionType=0&token=USDT&fiat=RUB&paymentMethod=75'

driver.get(bybit_url)
sleep(5)
print(driver.page_source)
```

Comment: _trying to get access to web site_: Code trials?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the *Access is Denied* as [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) driven *ChromeDriver* initiated [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) *Browsing Context* is getting detected as a [bot](/questions/tagged/bot).

To avoid the detection you need to use the argument [*`--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70709308/7429447) as follows:

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
```

Comment: Thank you for help, but I've got the same issue(

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem on Heroku trying to access bybit sites with selenium.
I used this user agent and it works for me:
'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/**106.0.0.0** Safari/537.36'

```
'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
```

Among many other trial and error attempts, I reached this user agent comparing user agents used locally and on Heroku.

Locally:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = os.environ.get( "GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
#options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.bybit.com/fiat/trade/otc/?actionType=0&token=USDT&fiat=RUB&paymentMethod=75") 

print(driver.page_source)
print(driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent"))
driver.quit()
```

Result:

```
(...)</iframe></html>
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Locally:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = os.environ.get( "GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.bybit.com/fiat/trade/otc/?actionType=0&token=USDT&fiat=RUB&paymentMethod=75")

print(driver.page_source)
print(driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent"))
driver.quit()
```

Result:

```
<html><head>
<title>Access Denied</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Access Denied</h1>

You don t have permission to access "http://www.bybit.com/fiat/trade/otc/?" on this server.<p>       
Reference #18.17bd2f17.1664927640.82fbfed7


</p></body></html>
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/106.0.5249.91 Safari/537.36
```

On Heroku:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import os

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = os.environ.get( "GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
print(driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent"))
driver.quit()
```

Result:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/106.0.5249.91 Safari/537.36
```

On Heroku:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = os.environ.get( "GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
user_agent ='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
options.add_argument('user-agent={0}'.format(user_agent))
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.bybit.com/fiat/trade/otc/?actionType=0&token=USDT&fiat=RUB&paymentMethod=75")

print(driver.page_source)
print(driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent"))
driver.quit()
```

Winning result:

```
(...)</iframe></html>
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```