# Cannot load the website I want to on remote PC through selenium compressed as exe file

Tags: python, selenium

I wrote some python script combine with selenium to login a website  automatically,it works well on my PC.
Now I compress the script as exe file to run on a remote PC,but it cannot load the page, stucks at "checking your browser before accessing xxx".
Why?
[image]

here is my code:

```
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
op.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches',['enable-logging'])
ser = Service('chromedriver.exe')
wd = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser,options=op)
wd.get(self.url)
# time.sleep(30)
try:

    email_input = WebDriverWait(wd,30).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"user_email"))
    )
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite evident from the [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YH4p.jpg) that [***cloudflare***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50328849/is-there-any-possible-ways-to-bypass-cloudflare-security-checks/64960388#64960388) have [detected your program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70508719/why-is-a-special-cookie-banner-not-displayed-in-the-selenium-chromedriver-test-s/70509053#70509053) as a [bot](/questions/tagged/bot) and further navigation is blocked.

To prevent detection you can add the following argument through *`add_argument()`*:

> > [`--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65994908/selenium-cant-open-a-second-page/65998533#65998533)

Sample Code Block:

```
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
op.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
op.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
op.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
op.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
ser = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
wd = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser,options=op)
wd.get(self.url)
```

Comment: sorry, bro, this approach doesn't work for me.