# Website recognising I am using a server whilst using selenium

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium, selenium-webdriver, bots, botdetect

I am trying to set up an automated sports betting bot using selenium and running it on selenium. When running the bot on the server the website recognises this and therefore doesn't allow me to deposit, but when running it off the server I don't run it into this problem.

I have tried using proxies and VPN's and this still doesn't fix the problem.

The website is [1xbit.com](https://1xbit.com/live/Football/) and this picture shows the error message when trying to deposit.[image]

Code:

```
def get_website():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path=pathway)
    driver.maximize_window()
    actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
    driver.get('https://1xbit.com/live/Football/')
    return driver
```

Essentially, I want to add code to hide the fact I am on a server....

Answer (score 0):

To avoid [detection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70509053/7429447) add the following argument through *`add_argument()`* as follows:

- [`--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65998533/7429447)

Sample Code:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
driver.get('https://1xbit.com/live/Football/')
```

Browser Screenshot:

[image: live_Football]

Comment: Still got the same result when trying to deposit...

Comment: @Joe What do you mean by deposit? In your code trials I only see you `driver.get()` and then `return driver`

Comment: Basically if you set up an account and then try to deposit you get a error message (when using the server), but when I don't use the server I don't get this error message.
I assume the website is picking up the fact I am on a server.

Comment: @Joe How can we repro the issue? Do you have a set of demo creds?

Comment: I have just set up a chat with you on the selenium chat room...